# How to integrate OpenMQ with Jboss-4.2.3.GA?

Tags: jms, jboss-4.2.x, openmq

I am trying to integrate OpenMq with Jboss-4.2.3.GA for my performance evaluation research for messaging oriented middlewares. I want to use imqjmsra.ra as a default resource adapter.
I need help in step by step process for integration of these two. i want to make OpenMq my default JMS provider for my jboss server. Documentation and exact links or proper steps will be hugely appreciated. please help.

Comment: StackOverflow generally doesn't give you step by step instructions. Try implementing yourself first, then come back with a specific question as to what your problem is.